# How to edit files from localhost via lynx?

Tags: html, documentroot

I want to optimize a site for viewing with `lynx`.

If I view any HTML file from outside of the `DocumentRoot`, I am able to edit and save these files inside `lynx` with keystroke `e`, which invokes `vim`.

Accessing files from `localhost` with `lynx http://localhost` works.

But if I try to change some content with `e`, lynx displays the message `lynx cannot currently edit remote www file`.

Whether `sudo lynx http://localhost` nor `sudo bash -c 'lynx http://localhost'` is solving this issue.

Default editor is set in `lynx.cfg` with `DEFAULT_EDITOR:/usr/bin/vim`.

Any hint to solve this issue is welcome.

**EDIT:** [@uprego:](https://serverfault.com/users/178024/uprego) Thank you for your effort. Your answer unfortunately is not related to my issue.

Answer (score 2):

> [To enable editing, documents must be referenced using a "file:" URL or by specifying a plain filename on the command line as in the following two examples](http://condor.cc.ku.edu/~grobe/docs/Lynx_users_guide.html#11):
>
> ```
> lynx file://localhost/FULL/PATH/FILENAME
> lynx path/filename.html
> ```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Sorry, no. This is not what I have mentioned. If I need to use some file scheme for accessing files in `DocumentRoot`, or have to type something from outside of lynx, I would simpley use **sudo** `vim any/file`. **from within lynx, with `e` command** is what I am looking for.